# Python subprocess IOError: [Errno 4]

Tags: python, subprocess, ioerror

I'm implementing python program which returns a result of subprocess(like 'ls'). 
The subprocess has a feature like subscribing continuous output, more specific, it subscribes two results, and there is short term(about 1sec) between two results.

So, I've designed a class like below for subscribing that output.

```
class Subscribe:
    def __init__(self, sec):
        self.m_sec = sec
    def subscribeResult(self, p):
        self.m_timeout = False
        signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, self.handleTimeout)
        signal.alarm(self.m_sec)
        returnValue = ""

        try:
            with p.stdout:
                for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
                    if self.m_timeout:
                        signal.alarm(0)
                        p.kill()
                        return "timeout"
                    returnValue += line
            p.stdout.close()
            p.wait()
        exception Exception, inst:
            print inst
            signal.alarm(0)
            p.kill()
            return "except"

        signal.alarm(0)
        rv = returnValue.strip()
        if rv == "":
            return "null"
        return rv
    def handleTimeout(self, signum, frame):
        self.m_timeout = True
```

It's working well, but very rarely raised IO exception like below.
: IOError: [Errno 4] Interrupted system call

Is there weak point in code? 
Please, let me know how to erase exception

Comment: You need to post the whole traceback message so that we can see where this exception comes from.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, just retry whatever system calls you were performing e.g., `subprocess` module has a helper function to ignore the `EINTR` error:

```
def _eintr_retry_call(func, *args):
    while True:
        try:
            return func(*args)
        except (OSError, IOError) as e:
            if e.errno == errno.EINTR:
                continue
            raise
```

Usage:

```
readline = _eintr_retry_call(p.stdout.readline)
```

In Python 3.5, it will happen automatically. See [PEP 0475 -- Retry system calls failing with EINTR](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0475/).